# URL Encoded characters in IE 9

Tags: url, encoding, internet-explorer-9, http-status-code-404, http-error

I have a problem hitting a URL and getting HTTP 404 error (No web page found). Some findings led me to conclude it is an encoding issue for one of the query parameters so I tried to apply urlEncoding i.e. HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<= 1 Week"). This produces "%3c%3d1+Week". But the problem persists. If no UrlEncode is done, the querystring will be "%3C=1%20Week"

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: can you show us an example of the full url that 404s?

Comment: It's something like this - https://www.myhost.com//test.aspx?Duration=%3c%3d2+Weeks

Comment: it's the double forward slashes causing the problem (should just be myhost.com/test.aspx?....)

Comment: I don't think so. If I just remove the parameter and put myhost.com//test.aspx, there is no problem hitting the url at all. You can try that with any url putting double slash and it still works in IE. I'm thinking there might be some setting in IE that can solve this issue.

Comment: interesting, I didn't know that; I'm thinking it's bad practise anyway though? as for the problem, the encoded url looks fine to me. does the page load if the query string doesn't contain characters that need encoding?